# Create checkmark for a Table View with a detail segue?

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, master-detail, checkmark

I would like to create an app with a list of TODO items. Each TODO should have a functional checkmark/checkbox on the left side of the cell. If I click on the right side of the TODO then I would like to show its details.

I have create a Table View. When I click on a cell I follow a segue to a UIViewController that shows the details of the cell.

I think displaying the checkmark may be possible by defining the cell's imageView. However, I can't make the imageView functional, i.e., clickable. Every time I click on it it simply shows the details.

Can you provide basic sample code to show how I can have both a segue to the details of the cell AND a checkmark that is clickable?

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: FYI: don't expect any answers here, since you only want to have something. And TBH this is some rather basic stuff which you can find answers for by Googling and reading docs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Added this code snippet:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapped"))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.imageView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

    //...
}

func tapped() {
        println("tapped!")
}
```